# PrimeFlex not rendering grid correctly

Tags: angular, primeng, primeflex

I have a new Angular project that I am trying to create the grid layour for. However, it is not rendering correctly.

This is the HTML:

```
<div class = "grid">
  <div class = "col-12"> Header/nav</div>
  <div class = "col-12"> Top tabs</div>
  <div class = "col-2">side nav</div>
  <div class = "col-7">main body</div>
  <div class = "col-5">widget</div>

</div>
```

But this is how it is rendering the data:

[image: scrennshot of rendered]

I added this to angular.json:

```
,
            "styles": [
              "node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/lara-light-blue/theme.css",
              "node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css",
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
```

and this to styles.scss

```
@import "primeng/resources/themes/lara-light-blue/theme.css";
@import "primeng/resources/primeng.css";
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you want to use [primeflex grid](https://www.primefaces.org/primeflex/gridsystem)

To use it make sure you have the dependency in `package.json` -> `"primeflex": "^3.3.0"` and style imported in `angular.json`

```
"architect": {
  "build": {
    ....
    "styles": [
      "./node_modules/primeflex/primeflex.css",
      "src/styles.css"
    ],
  }
}
```

See config in this [stackblitz primeflex example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primefaces-dt3juu?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Answer (score 0):

package.json

```
"@angular/core": "^17.2.0",
"primeflex": "^3.3.1",
"primeng": "^17.10.0",
```

I am faceing the same Problem,
and I found that the classes ( grid, col, col-1, etc... ) do not exist in "primeflex/themes/**primeone-light.css**" but they are existed in "primeflex/**primeflex.css**".

so I fixed that problem by improting the both files into style.scss

style.scss

```
@import "primeflex/themes/primeone-light.css";
@import "primeflex/primeflex.css";
```

- do not forget to add primeng css files too.